# Storing user data example - display name not showing in database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

A bit confused why there's no display name being displayed in my Firebase database, I've followed the steps in the example on their website and didn't get the expected result which they showed. Here's the example code.

```
final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword("jenny@example.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple",
    new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        // Authentication just completed successfully :)
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("provider", authData.getProvider());
        if(authData.getProviderData().containsKey("displayName")) {
            map.put("displayName", authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
        }
        ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError error) {
        // Something went wrong :(
    }
});
```

Whenever I tried this example code the expected result was to be something similar to what is shown below.

```
{
  "users": {
    "6d914336-d254-4fdb-8520-68b740e047e4": {
      "displayName": "alanisawesome",
      "provider": "password"
    },
    "002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386": {
      "displayName": "gracehop",
      "provider": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of showing something similar to the above, in my database only the provider is shown and not the displayName. Is there any necessary steps required to get the displayName to show or should it be there automatically?

I tried to look into this to see what was included within `authData.getProviderData()` and this was what was produced in the console when I printed it out.

```
01-25 17:58:51.921 15651-15651/<package-name> I/System.out: {email=j.joe@hotmail.co.uk, isTemporaryPassword=false, profileImageURL=https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/de53da9874178adb1a44b392ba5bed2f?d=retro}
```

So from the result produced it's left me wondering if the key "displayName" was formerly automatically created from the email and stored by default in `authData.getProviderData()` and that's why it is no longer shown.

Would appreciate it if someone could explain where the displayName in the database comes from because judging by the expected result it seems I've missed something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An email+password account does not have an associated display name. It only requires an email address and a password.

You can definitely require the user to enter additional information. Just don't pass it to `createUser()` and don't overwrite it after calling `authWithPassword()`.

**Update**: since the update to Firebase Authentication released at Google I/O 2016, there is now a *display name* property for each user. So you can also keep the display name in Firebase Authentication itself (although you won't be able to query/search for it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is display name only associated with social media websites which has display names like Twitter and GitHub?

Comment: All social provider that Firebase Authentication currently supports (Github, Twitter, Facebook and Google) have a `displayName`. The only provider that doesn't have this property is email+password.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  @FrankvanPuffelen, I saw your response about displayName, but when the user signs up using email/password the UI asks for a First and Last name.  Is there a way to access/store this data for the displayName or at least store it in another field in the database?

Comment: This is an answer from back before I/O. In Firebase Authentication we released at I/O, each user *does* have a display name property that you can set/change. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the quick response...still not storing though..  I'm using this provider:  AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build()     When I try to access that user's displayName, it show's as null.  The email is returned correctly that is used for the sign in