# After creating a user with email and password in Firebase, setting users display name doesn't work with profilechangerequest. (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Having trouble setting current users display name after user creates account with email and password. After the `onCompleteListener` fires in the `createUSerWithEmailAndPassword` I try to then make a `UserProfileChangeRequest` on the current user, the `onCompleteListner` fires and task was successful but when I get current user displayname it returns `null`. Has anyone else had this problem been stuck on it for a few days now, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Create account function]

[image: Set display name function]

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35005526/4815718.  As I read it, display name is not supported for a user created with email/password.

Comment: For your next SO question, it's better to post your code as text instead of image.  Then we can copy and run it more easily.